# Aks workload identity with deamon set

Tags: azure-aks, workload-identity

i'm trying to integrate aks workload identity with elastic-agent deamon set. The yaml of elastic-agent is automatically generated by elastic cloud instance and it is this one:

```
---
# For more information refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/running-on-kubernetes-managed-by-fleet.html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
  namespace: elastic-cloud
  labels:
    app: elastic-agent
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elastic-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elastic-agent
        azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elastic-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elastic-agent
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        hype.type: "default"
      # Tolerations are needed to run Elastic Agent on Kubernetes control-plane nodes.
      # Agents running on control-plane nodes collect metrics from the control plane components (scheduler, controller manager) of Kubernetes
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
          effect: NoSchedule
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      serviceAccountName: elastic-agent
      hostNetwork: true
      # 'hostPID: true' enables the Elastic Security integration to observe all process exec events on the host.
      # Sharing the host process ID namespace gives visibility of all processes running on the same host.
      hostPID: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
        - name: elastic-agent
          image: docker.elastic.co/beats/elastic-agent:8.8.2
          env:
            # Set to 1 for enrollment into Fleet server. If not set, Elastic Agent is run in standalone mode
            - name: FLEET_ENROLL
              value: "1"
            # Set to true to communicate with Fleet with either insecure HTTP or unverified HTTPS
            - name: FLEET_INSECURE
              value: "true"
            # Fleet Server URL to enroll the Elastic Agent into
            # FLEET_URL can be found in Kibana, go to Management > Fleet > Settings
            - name: FLEET_URL
              value: "MY FLEET URL"
            # Elasticsearch API key used to enroll Elastic Agents in Fleet (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/fleet-enrollment-tokens.html#fleet-enrollment-tokens)
            # If FLEET_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN is empty then KIBANA_HOST, KIBANA_FLEET_USERNAME, KIBANA_FLEET_PASSWORD are needed
            - name: FLEET_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN
              value: MY TOKEN
            - name: KIBANA_HOST
              value: "http://kibana:5601"
            # The basic authentication username used to connect to Kibana and retrieve a service_token to enable Fleet
            - name: KIBANA_FLEET_USERNAME
              value: "elastic"
            # The basic authentication password used to connect to Kibana and retrieve a service_token to enable Fleet
            - name: KIBANA_FLEET_PASSWORD
              value: "changeme"
            - name: NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
            # The following capabilities are needed for 'Defend for containers' integration (cloud-defend)
            # If you are using this integration, please uncomment these lines before applying.
            #capabilities:
            #  add:
            #    - BPF # (since Linux 5.8) allows loading of BPF programs, create most map types, load BTF, iterate programs and maps.
            #    - PERFMON # (since Linux 5.8) allows attaching of BPF programs used for performance metrics and observability operations.
            #    - SYS_RESOURCE # Allow use of special resources or raising of resource limits. Used by 'Defend for Containers' to modify 'rlimit_memlock'
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 400m
              memory: 500Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 500Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: proc
              mountPath: /hostfs/proc
              readOnly: true
            - name: cgroup
              mountPath: /hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup
              readOnly: true
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
              readOnly: true
            - name: etc-full
              mountPath: /hostfs/etc
              readOnly: true
            - name: var-lib
              mountPath: /hostfs/var/lib
              readOnly: true
            - name: etc-mid
              mountPath: /etc/machine-id
              readOnly: true
            - name: sys-kernel-debug
              mountPath: /sys/kernel/debug
      volumes:
        - name: proc
          hostPath:
            path: /proc
        - name: cgroup
          hostPath:
            path: /sys/fs/cgroup
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        # The following volumes are needed for Cloud Security Posture integration (cloudbeat)
        # If you are not using this integration, then these volumes and the corresponding
        # mounts can be removed.
        - name: etc-full
          hostPath:
            path: /etc
        - name: var-lib
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib
        # Mount /etc/machine-id from the host to determine host ID
        # Needed for Elastic Security integration
        - name: etc-mid
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/machine-id
            type: File
        # Needed for 'Defend for containers' integration (cloud-defend)
        # If you are not using this integration, then these volumes and the corresponding
        # mounts can be removed.
        - name: sys-kernel-debug
          hostPath:
            path: /sys/kernel/debug
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: elastic-agent
    namespace: elastic-cloud
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: elastic-agent
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  namespace: elastic-cloud
  name: elastic-agent
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: elastic-agent
    namespace: elastic-cloud
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: elastic-agent
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent-kubeadm-config
  namespace: elastic-cloud
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: elastic-agent
    namespace: elastic-cloud
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: elastic-agent-kubeadm-config
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
  labels:
    k8s-app: elastic-agent
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes
      - namespaces
      - events
      - pods
      - services
      - configmaps
      # Needed for cloudbeat
      - serviceaccounts
      - persistentvolumes
      - persistentvolumeclaims
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  # Enable this rule only if planing to use kubernetes_secrets provider
  #- apiGroups: [""]
  #  resources:
  #  - secrets
  #  verbs: ["get"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions"]
    resources:
      - replicasets
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources:
      - statefulsets
      - deployments
      - replicasets
      - daemonsets
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes/stats
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups: [ "batch" ]
    resources:
      - jobs
      - cronjobs
    verbs: [ "get", "list", "watch" ]
  # Needed for apiserver
  - nonResourceURLs:
      - "/metrics"
    verbs:
      - get
  # Needed for cloudbeat
  - apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
    resources:
      - clusterrolebindings
      - clusterroles
      - rolebindings
      - roles
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  # Needed for cloudbeat
  - apiGroups: ["policy"]
    resources:
      - podsecuritypolicies
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [ "storage.k8s.io" ]
    resources:
      - storageclasses
    verbs: [ "get", "list", "watch" ]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
  # Should be the namespace where elastic-agent is running
  namespace: elastic-cloud
  labels:
    k8s-app: elastic-agent
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - coordination.k8s.io
    resources:
      - leases
    verbs: ["get", "create", "update"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent-kubeadm-config
  namespace: elastic-cloud
  labels:
    k8s-app: elastic-agent
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - kubeadm-config
    verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    azure.workload.identity/client-id: MY WORKLOAD IDENITYT ID
  name: elastic-agent
  namespace: elastic-cloud
  labels:
    k8s-app: elastic-agent
---
```

with https://akv2k8s.io/ i just modify:

```
        - name: FLEET_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN
          value: MY TOKEN
```

with secretname@azurekeyvault. It automatically inject the secret inside pods. With workload identity i modify the service account creation adding:

```
  annotations:
    azure.workload.identity/client-id: MY WORKLOAD IDENITYT ID
```

and deamon set:

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elastic-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elastic-agent
        azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
```

after that i follow microsoft doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-deploy-cluster but i do not understand how i have to setup the value to call secret. In Microsoft example they do:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: quick-start
  namespace: elastic-cloud
  labels:
    azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
spec:
  serviceAccountName: elastic-agent
  containers:
    - image: ghcr.io/azure/azure-workload-identity/msal-go
      name: oidc
      env:
      - name: KEYVAULT_URL
        value: https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/
      - name: SECRET_NAME
        value: mysecret
```

i tried to test the sa with last yaml and it call correctly the secret.

Comment: Setup the value as in? You have to first have the keyvault and secret ready in your azure portal seperately and then call them here by updating the value with your own keyvault url and secret available under secret section of your keyvault

Comment: keyvault and secret already exist, I currently use them by calling them with the ak2v8s integration.

What do you mean?